# How to rename a docker image in the remote registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have an images in my remote docker registry:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx:5000/library/ruby:2.2.1
```

Is there a quick way or existing command to rename it?

I know I can implement this by executing `docker pull` it to local and rename it by `docker tag` and then `docker push` again.

```
docker pull xx.xx.xx.xx:5000/library/ruby:2.2.1
docker tag xx.xx.xx.xx:5000/library/ruby:2.2.1  xx.xx.xx:5000/library/new_name:latest
docker push xx.xx.xx.xx:5000/library/new_name:latest
```

But since pulling and push images cost time, I wonder if there is an quick way to rename it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can perform the rename in a single step using [skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo), like this:

```
skopeo copy \
  docker://xx.xx.xx.xx:5000/library/ruby:2.2.1 \
  docker://xx.xx.xx.xx:5000/library/new_name:latest
```

If the source and destination image are in the same namespace (which these are), this should not require actually copying any data because the layers already exist in the target. The same is true of your pull/retag/push procedure, but this is a single step so perhaps more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different methods:


**a)** If you just want to change the **TAG**:
the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38362476/8430173 works only for changing **TAG**



**b)** If you want to change the repository name too:

by many thanks to [this](https://dille.name/blog/2018/09/20/how-to-tag-docker-images-without-pulling-them/), I changed the repoName too!

(by help of his [Github](https://github.com/nicholasdille/PowerShell-RegistryDocker/tree/0.7.5.6) project):

1- get manifests (in v2 schema)
2- post every layer.digest in the new repo
3- post config.layer
4- put whole manifest to new repo

### details:

**1- GET** manifest from `reg:5000/v2/{oldRepo}/manifests/{oldtag}` with`accept` header:`application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json`

**2-** for every layer : **POST** `reg:5000/v2/{newRepo}/blobs/uploads/?mount={layer.digest}&from={oldRepoNameWithaoutTag}`

**3- POST** `reg:5000/v2/{newRepo}/blobs/uploads/?mount={config.digest}&from={oldRepoNameWithaoutTag}`

**4- PUT** `reg:5000/v2/{newRepo}/manifests/{newTag}` with `content-type` header:`application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json` and `body` from step 1 response

**5-** enjoy!