# how to tag image in docker registry v2

Tags: docker, docker-registry

We have logic in our CI-CD that tags (via REST) staging image to `latest` (if tests are successful). This worked on registry v1.

We now moved to v2 api, and I can't find documentation on how to "add" tags to existing image in registry. I'm in a step that can bring the "manifest" of some staging image, but not sure how to add tag and POST it via http.

I tried to send the following inputs:

1. `"tag": "staging","latest",`
2. `"tag": ["staging","latest"],` and more

```json
{
    "schemaVersion": 1,
    "name": "configservice",
    "tag": "staging",
    "architecture": "amd64",
    "fsLayers": [...
```

Comment: There are multiple tools that do this today, including skopeo, crane, and regclient.

Answer (score 33):

If you have Docker Registry that supports manifest schema version 2, you can just upload the manifest of an existing image under a new tag.

For example let's assume that you want to tag latest version of `busybox` image. The steps would be:

**Download the existing manifest:**

```bash
curl '<registry_url>/v2/mybusybox/manifests/latest' \
-H 'accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json' \
> manifest.json
```

**Here's what the manifest might look like (notice that schemaVersion is 2):**

```json
{
   "schemaVersion": 2,
   "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
   "config": {
      "mediaType": "application/octet-stream",
      "size": 1459,
      "digest": "sha256:2b8fd9751c4c0f5dd266fcae00707e67a2545ef34f9a29354585f93dac906749"
   },
   "layers": [
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
         "size": 667590,
         "digest": "sha256:8ddc19f16526912237dd8af81971d5e4dd0587907234be2b83e249518d5b673f"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Upload the manifest under a new tag:**

```bash
curl -XPUT '<registry_url>/v2/mybusybox/manifests/new_tag' \
-H 'content-type: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json' \
-d '@manifest.json'
```

Detailed step-by-step guide is give in this [post](https://wheleph.gitlab.io/posts/2016-07-13-tagging-using-docker-registry-http-api-v2/).

Comment: You should post the instructions here in case the website goes down -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Doesn't work for me using a nexus3 docker registry.
<Response [404]>
{"errors":[{"code":"MANIFEST_UNKNOWN","message":"manifest unknown","detail":[{"Name":"testrepo"},{"Tag":"newtag"}]}]}

Comment: Regarding my last comment, I think this is a bug in nexus, so I made a ticket: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-27253

Comment: What is the repository URL for docker hub?

Answer (score 23):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but I have always done the following...

```bash
docker pull myimage:staging
docker run myimage:staging test  # this is optional
docker tag myimage:staging myimage:release
docker push myimage:release
```

Note that `docker pull` will download the image, but if layers already exists on the registry, `docker push` will not upload everything again.

Comment: This is definitely a working solution, but it requires to have docker binary, possibly running it as root. Also it might take considerable amount of time, because it involves image downloading.

Comment: Based on the question, we are running tests on the image to validate it- so it must already exist (either having been built or downloaded) on the CI machine.  This doesn't introduce any additional concerns that the "test" step doesn't (just the lag from the second `docker push` which is quite fast in the event of a retag.

Comment: This does not work if you have multi-platform images and the original image you are trying to re-tag is not on the local machine (i.e. you first have to pull it). This is because "docker pull" only pulls the image layers that match the local machine's platform architecture, then if you push the new tag(s) you will only push an image with a single platform architecture layer.

Answer (score 10):

I just wanted to add, since this came up in my search results, that Google Container Registry includes [the `add-tag` command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/add-tag) to do this directly.

```bash
gcloud container images add-tag gcr.io/project/image:old-tag gcr.io/project/image:new-tag
```

The workflow described by wheleph above worked, but resulted in the creation of a new container rather than applying an additional tag to the existing one.

Comment: And here is how to do the equivalent in AWS: https://davin.ninja/amazon-ecr-adding-tag-image-already-pushed

Comment: Just as a clarification- the `docker tag && docker push` workflow above does NOT actually create any new containers (or images). When the daemon or registry sees that a tag refers to the same underlying image, the API just adds a reference from the new tag to the old image. The registry api is the same, the new manifest refers to the same underlying images/layers. The api provided by ecr and gcloud is of course nicer though :)

Comment: If memory serves, I tested Google Cloud's behaviour at the time and found that it interpreted the command as creating a new image, although of course that was several years ago. As for retagging from the API, both Google Cloud and AQS have the advantage that their APIs don't require you to have a local copy of the image, which might be friendlier to some workflows.

Comment: The described method for AWS doesn't appear to work anymore, but instead creates a new image in the ECR repository rather than adding a tag to an existing image.

Answer (score 5):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38362476/8430173) works only for changing image **tag**, but I wanted to change the **repository name** too.

Thanks to [Nicholas Dille's 'How to tag docker images without pulling them' post](https://dille.name/blog/2018/09/20/how-to-tag-docker-images-without-pulling-them/), I was able to change the `repoName` too! With help from [his `nicholasdille/PowerShell-RegistryDocker` project](https://github.com/nicholasdille/PowerShell-RegistryDocker/tree/0.7.5.6) project:

1. get manifests (in v2 schema)
2. post every layer.digest in the new repo
3. post config.layer
4. put whole manifest to new repo

### details:

1. **GET** manifest from `reg:5000/v2/{oldRepo}/manifests/{oldtag}` with`accept` header:`application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json`
2. For every layer : **POST** `reg:5000/v2/{newRepo}/blobs/uploads/?mount={layer.digest}&from={oldRepoNameWithaoutTag}`
3. **POST** `reg:5000/v2/{newRepo}/blobs/uploads/?mount={config.digest}&from={oldRepoNameWithaoutTag}`
4. **PUT** `reg:5000/v2/{newRepo}/manifests/{newTag}` with `content-type` header:`application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json` and `body` from step 1 response
5. enjoy!

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this with [docker buildx imagetools create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_imagetools_create/)

```
docker buildx imagetools create myregistry.com/myimage:latest --tag myregistry.com/myimage:staging
```

this will simply download the image manifest of `myregistry.com/myimage:latest` and re-tag (and push) it as `myregistry.com/myimage:staging`

NOTE: this will also retain the multi-platform manifest list when you "re-tag" (e.g. when your image is build for both linux/arm64 and linux/amd64). Where as the conventional docker pull/push strategy will only retain the image manifest for the platform/architecture of the system you do the pull/push from.

P.S. this is repost of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70526615/1514235)